# Do you know any good introduction to JMS for IBM MQ (MQSeries) person?

Tags: jms, ibm-mq

I've been looking for a good JMS introduction for the person who knows IBM MQ (MQSeries) very well. She is very experienced working with MQ-based systems on mainframe, but she asked me about the overview of the JMS to see how JMS relates to MQ and what is important when implementedin the application using JMS provided by MQ. Any URLs would be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Book:
MQSeries Programming Patterns

Some Tutorials: 
http://www.academictutorials.com/jms/jsm-mqseries.asp

JMS/MQSeries Samples :
http://www-304.ibm.com/jct01005c/isv/tech/sampmq.html#java

An important issue while installing MQSeries
http://www.simongbrown.com/blog/2003/11/27/setting_up_jms_with_websphere_mq.html

Answer (score 1):

The following IBM redbook is good book to refer. Chapter 8 
http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/redbooks/pdfs/sg246506.pdf

Regards,
Ashok